# Kill a Process for a User

Tags: perl

```
chomp $choice;
if ($choice == 5) {
   print "**********************************\n";
   print " Enter the User Name\n";
   $user_name = <STDN>;

   sub kill_processes {
      $user_name = <STDN> ;
      @process_list = `ps -u $user_name| awk ' { print $2 ;} ' `;
      print @process_list;
      print "Are you sure you want to kill all of these processes? (Y|N) >";
      $resp = <STDIN> ;
      chomp $resp;
      if ( $resp eq "Y" || $resp eq 'y' ) {
         foreach (@process_list) {
            if ( ! /PID/ ) {
               @process = split / /, $_;
               print "Killing Process $process[1]\n";
               `kill -09 $process[1]`;
            }
         }
      }
   }



}
```

This is only part of the code I can't get to work. Everything works fine when I select
choice 5 but it doesn't do anything when I enter the user name? How can I get this this
to work?

Comment: a) The read on <STDIN> to find out the user name is duplicated b) You're not even calling the `kill_processes` sub.

Comment: I corrected the <STDIN> part but how do I call out the sub?

Comment: Move line 4 of the above code into the subroutine body and remove line 5 altogether, then add `&kill_processes()` after the statement that prints a lot of asterisks.

Comment: Also try pattern matching. Change `if ( $resp eq "Y" || $resp eq 'y' ) {` to `if ( $resp =~ /^y$/i ) {` Also, I'd strongly recommend turning on `warnings` and using `strict` which I am guessing that you haven't done given I can't see any `my` when declaring your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm....would it not be easier to use the already provided command:

```
 killall -u username
```

Of course, it would have to be run as root.